# Avoiding repeating code on API Actions but still supporting multi language

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5

My goal is to create an API that supports multiple languages.

It is working, but only if I call

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
```

on each Action, something that I suppose that can be avoided.

---

On WebApiConfig.cs file I created a route to support multiple languages, placing that language before the default route `"{lang}/api/{controller}/{id}"`. That means that for English I can call `http://localhost/en/api/service/get` and for Portuguese `http://localhost/pt/api/service/get`.

**WebApiConfig.cs:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiLocalized",
            routeTemplate: "{lang}/api/{controller}/{id}",
            constraints: new { lang = @"(\w{2})|(\w{2}-\w{2})"}, // en or en-US
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

---

On my Action I receive the language and use it to change the Culture.

**ServiceController.cs**

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get(string lang)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
        return Resources.Global.Country;
    }
}
```

---

When I call `http://localhost/en/api/service/get` or `http://localhost/pt/api/service/get` I get the string in their respective languages, working perfectly.

How can I avoid using

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
```

on all Actions?

Where can I write it once in the code, but still getting the needed `lang` argument?

- I've tried **Global.asax.cs**, but I don't know if I can (and how) get that `lang` argument.
- I don't know if I can (and how) put it on **WebApiConfig.cs**.

Comment: Any reason you want the language in the URL rather than as a query parameter? The latter feels like a cleaner option to me... or take it from the existing headers in the request, of course.

Comment: Looking again, it seems like your question isn't *really* about the routing - it's about "how do I get a resource for a specific language". It would be helpful if you'd remove the extraneous routing part.

Comment: It would help if you'd show the type of `Resources.Global` btw. My guess is that it's a generated class with a `ResourceManager` property that you could use to fetch a string with a particular culture.

Comment: May be you are looking for an action filter which gets executed in every request, read the url segment value and set it to the thread ?. you can register this globally

Comment: @JonSkeet 1. The language in the URL makes it easier and more reliable to make an API call for a language. 2. The routing part shows how I get the language and how I'm getting the lang argument on the action. 3. They are generated Resources with the key-value translations. I have one Global.resx for PT and Global.en.resx for EN.

Comment: @Shyju I think that is what I'm looking for, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: My point is that the routing part appears to be working, so is irrelevant, right? You just need a way of getting the resources given a `CultureInfo`, yes? In which case that's what you should concentrate on. No need to change the thread culture unless that's genuinely helpful to you.

Comment: @Edu I posted an answer about how to create an action filter so that you can put the duplicate code in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after removing some code from all your action method and want that in a central place to avoid code duplication, you may consider creating an action filter and apply it globally so that it will be applicable to all requests.

```
public class LangSettingActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var routeData= actionContext.Request.GetRouteData();
        object langCode;
        if (routeData.Values.TryGetValue("lang", out langCode))
        {
          //the languageCode from url is in langCode variable. Use it as needed.
          //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                                    //CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(langCode.ToString());

        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

You can register this filter globally inside the `Register` method of your `WebApiConfig` class.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   // Your existing route definiton here
   config.Filters.Add(new LangSettingActionFilter());
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. That was what I needed. It applies to all actions without needing to set the Culture in every one of them. Thank you Shyju.